# Validation of canonical links not working in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

I internationalized my site's canonical links using the guide from here: https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/#hreflang-canonical

Which has an output like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en-gb/" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en-au/" hreflang="en-au" />

<!-- If we were on the en-gb page, only the canonical would change: -->

<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/en-gb/">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en-gb/" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en-au/" hreflang="en-au" />
```

Except my site uses URL parameters instead of separate links, like `https://www.example.com?hl=de`.

The tags are correctly generated in the HTML but I have asked google to revalidate links twice and they are not being added into the index. I have an example screenshot below.

Could the URL parameters be causing this? Or perhaps the empty hreflang attribute in the link tag? Or do I just need to keep trying to validate and wait for it to take effect?

[image]

Comment: "Except my site uses URL parameters instead of separate links," - Hhhmm, it would seem the code you've posted is just copied from the article you've linked to, not your actual code?! From your (incomplete) screenshot it would seem you are indeed using URL params (these are still "separate links" though?) - this is not a problem in itself, providing you are consistent. But why do you have an "empty hreflang attribute" (there is no empty `hreflang` attrib in the code you posted)?!

Comment: ... ah, I see that is the `canonical` tag, but why do you have an `hreflang` attribute at all on that element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bug in my canonical generation logic. Once I got it to match the blog it is showing up correctly in SEO. I am revalidating now.